# Print every two letters pairs in python3

Tags: python, alphabetical

I'm new to Python and I'm stuck in an exercise which tells me to provide a script printing every possible pairs of two letters, only lower case, one by line, ordered alphabetically and that is the closest thing that I could do

```
import string 
x=string.ascii_lowercase
y=list(x)
for i in y:
    print(i,end='')
    for g in y:
        print(g)
```

Comment: Is this generating an error, if so, what? What is your question here?

Comment: I think the print in the outer loop probably means it prints, `aa` `b` `c` etc. instead of `aa` `ab` `ac` - just print both `i` and `g` in the inner loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the i letter in the second for loop

```
import string 
x=string.ascii_lowercase
   
for i in x:
    for g in x:
        print(i,g)
```

So the program will go through every letter in the first loop and will print then the whole alphabet, one by one, as the second letter in the second loop

Answer (score 2):

You only print the first letter of each pair once.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercase_letters

for first_letter in lowercase_letters:
    for second_letter in lowercase_letters:
        print(first_letter + second_letter)
```

Additionally:

- You don't need to convert the string to a list, you can loop over a string just fine. In fact, that's how `list(some_string)` works!
- I used more readable variable names.
- Using `from ... import` means you don't need to have the additional assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will print in alphabetic order

You have studied ASCII code so what it does is it loops through 97 to 122 which contains all the alphabets and then it joins them.

```
for firstchar in range(97, 123):
    for secondchar in range(97, 123):
          print(chr(firstchar) + chr(secondchar))
```

Comment: I think it is simple and is using standard coding rather then just importing stuff which is just useless

Comment: Interesting approach.  Upvote for lower level thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list = ['WELCOME']
double_letters = []
for word in word_list:
    for i,j in enumerate(word):
        x = word[i:i+2]
        if len(x) == 2:
            double_letters.append(x)
print(double_letters)
```

If you are given a list of words. Then this is one possible way

Answer (score 0):

If use string module it is very simple task:

```
import string

for firstchar in string.ascii_lowercase:
    for secondchar in string.ascii_lowercase:
        print(firstchar + secondchar)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details. How does the input string look like?

Comment: In python string.ascii_lowercase will give you the lowercase letters from small "a" to... "z". Somewhere I read that it is like a pre-initialized string used as "string constant".